# Больше одного результата функции

Tags: python

В моей функции 2 выражение и 2 результата, которые требуется получить. (или больше) Правильно их записывать в return через запятую? Если я выполняю функцию, также получаю результаты через запятую. А как их получить по отдельности?

```
    def fu():
        a=2
        b=3
        c= a*b
        d = a/b
        return c,d
    print(fu()) #(6, 0.6666666666666666)
```

Comment: [Кортежи (tuple) | Python 3 для начинающих и чайников](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/kortezhi-tuple.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так же через запятую распаковать:

```
x, y = fu()
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Так сильно я давно не удивлялся.

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле, ответ выше немного неполный, я Вам поясню:
Когда вы пишите в return x,y,..., на самом деле питон делает неявное преобразование к типу tuple, т.е. по сути кортеж, который является неизменяемым типом данных (в отличие от списка) и когда вы пишите:
`x,y = fu()`, вы по сути пишите: `x,y = (X,Y)`, поэтому это корректно работает.

P.S. Любые значения через запятую без указания типа приводятся к кортежам.

Comment: Для того чтобы лучше почувствовать, то что я написал, выполните пару строк:

Comment: `print(type(fu(), fu())`

Answer (score -1):

Не рекомендуется, но возможно назначить переменные иначе. Вы можете сразу добавить имена в пространство глобальных переменных и в функции ничего не возвращать:

```
def fu():
    a = 2
    b = 3
    globals()["c"] = a * b
    globals()["d"] = a * b**-1

fu()
print c
print d
# 6
# 0.666666666667
```

Comment: Я думаю, что если автор пишет на Python 3, то не стоит показывать код из Python 2.

Comment: метка простой `python`